# 'ssh -x -a -oClearAllForwardings=yes' running on my machine

Tags: ssh, dbus

I have a process with the following name:

```
ssh -x -a -oClearAllForwardings=yes -2 user@host -s sftp
```

running on my machine, not for the first time, and I don't remember running such (I have obscured the names `user` and `host`, but other than that the command is the same). Under that, I have `ssh user@host` running, which I remember calling, and under that the following:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d
```

I have tried to kill these, without root permissions, but both with `SIGKILL` and with `SIGHUP`, with no luck. Do you have any idea what could it be?